# How to use Proxies && Proxy

Tags: proxy

I appreciate your help

I've never had the need to learn proxies until recently,

basically I have a Java application and I'm unsure if I can just setup a program so that my computer changes to use a different proxy every few minutes (out of a few 100-1000 proxies), or if I need to have the java application directly connect to a proxy in order for it to use the proxy? then finally I want to connect to website with basic get requests etc.

if anyone could kindly explain the process in order to accomplish what I explained and/or suggest how to go about performing this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to change proxy for OS network connection or the Java application that you are writing?

Answer (score 0):

you can start with SamProxy 1.0 it is very efficient proxy built in java
http://sourceforge.net/projects/samproxy10/?
you will need to update java JRE first.
There is readme File in project which will help you